# Overlay div on google map without using position absolute

Tags: css, google-maps

I am using the google maps API and I want to overlay a div so I have done this.

HTML

```
<div class="map-container">

<div class="radius-container">
    <h3>Raduis</h3>
    <select name="radius" class="js-radius">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    <h3>mile(s)</h3>
</div>

<div id="map" class="map"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.radius-container {

    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 95px;
    left: 245px;
    z-index: 99;
    background-color: $orange;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;

    select {
        width: 60px;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 5px 0;
    }
}

    .map-container {
    position: relative;
}
```

This does position the div how I want it but I have elements that slidedown on the page so when the element slides down the absolute div stays where it is messing up the design.

Does anyone know how I can position this without using position absolute??

Thanks

Comment: Screenshots would be great help. It's guess work at the moment.

Comment: Other elements on the page shouldn't affect the map/radius divs - unless they are also in `.map-container`.

Answer (score 1):

You could make it relative positioned and then change the left: 245px; property to margin-left: 245px; and then change the top property to margin-top and give it a negative value. For instance margin-top: -25px;

Comment: Thanks for the tip but that didnt work, I have decided to drop the overlay and try a different approach. Thanks anyway.